# How to delete rows from 3 tables based on a specific value in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Helo Folks,

I have 3 tables. `A`,`B`,`C`.

I have in Table `A` rows whose column'`date`' has  value '`2000-1-1`'.

I like to delete rows from **3** tables based on `where A.date = '2000-1-1'`.

Considering a `join on A.ID = B.ID`..  or some other kind of join between tables.

Comment: How about cascading deletes?

Comment: You can't delete from three tables at the same time. You need three separate statements.

Comment: A DML statement (insert, delete, etc) can only affect one table.

Comment: The question is about "how to do it", they don't require one statement. This can be done with 3 statements, inside a transaction.

Comment: We're going to need more information if you want an answer to your question. Are you looking for multiple statements, a stored procedure, a set of triggers?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot issue a single delete statement against 3 table but you can wrap 3 delete statements against 3 different tables in One Transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DELETE FROM TABLE_A
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Table_X X
                  WHERE TABLE_A.ID = X.ID)

    DELETE FROM TABLE_B
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Table_X X
                  WHERE TABLE_B.ID = X.ID)

    DELETE FROM TABLE_C
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Table_X X
                  WHERE TABLE_C.ID = X.ID)

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: what is table X? fourth table?